# How to add Xcode aggregate target on Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: xcode, xcode6.1.1

I don't know how to add Xcode aggregate target on Xcode 6.1.1, previously there was an option under the newfile->other->aggregate. But I don't know where in this version of Xcode the aggregate target template is.

Comment: I got it! We need to choose Add target section in on the Project settings!

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 6 this was moved to File -> New -> Target -> Other -> Aggregate

[image: xcode]